# Can I avoid specifying the same color value more than once in colors.xml?

Tags: android, android-resources

I have some colours which are reused in several different parts of my Android UI design. I am declaring the colours as resources in `colors.xml` with meaningful names:

```xml
<color name="action_bar_background">#1a404f</color>
<color name="edit_heading_background">#1a404f</color>
```

When I have multiple different definitions for the same colour value (as in the above example), is there a way of specifying the actual value of `#1a404f` just once? Or do I have to move away from naming the colours semantically, and give them names like `dark_blue` instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define one colour in terms of another, like this:

```xml
<color name="dark_blue">#1a404f</color>

<color name="action_bar_background">@color/dark_blue</color>
<color name="edit_heading_background">@color/dark_blue</color>
```